# The angular-isotope + isotope don't works well with my grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-isotope

I'm building a site with angular. In the main page and search results page has a recipes feed like a pinterest and I use the jQuery [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin and [angular-isotope](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope) directives, but I have 2 issues/problems.

In the main page a the grid cells do not have a fixed width, I use the min-width css property.

This is my CSS:

```
.recipe {
    width: $grid-width;
    min-height: 325px;
    height: auto;
    margin: $margin-top 0 $margin-bottom $ditter;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    @include border-radius(0 0 5px 5px);

    .avatar {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        width: $grid-width;
        margin: 0 auto;
        img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    .image {
        width: $grid-width - 2px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        img {
            width: $grid-width;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    .name {
        font-family: Times;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .recipe-controls {
        width: $grid-width;
        .star {
            font-size: 30px;
            margin: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my angular template:

```
<div id="masonry" class="clearfix" isotope-container>
  <div isotope-item>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="controls" isotope-item>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="recipe" ng-repeat="recipe in recipes" isotope-item>
    <div class="avatar text-center">
        <a href="">
            <img class="img-circle" ng-src="http://graph.facebook.com/bruno.egermano/picture?type=normal" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <a href="" ng-click="openRecipe(recipe.id)">
            <img ng-src="{{recipe.image}}" alt="{{recipe.name}}">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <a href="" ng-click="openRecipe(recipe.id)">{{recipe.name}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-controls">
        <i class="glyphicon  pull-right star" ng-class="{'glyphicon-star-empty': !recipe.star.stared, 'glyphicon-star': recipe.star.stared}">
            {{recipe.star.count}}
        </i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And that is my screenshoot, the circles is the problems I got.
[image: isotope-issue1]

In this first problem. What am I doing wrong?

The second problem, in the search result page, I have a filters, when the users change one of theirs, I call a ajax request and reload the collection.

When its occurs the isotope put all the items on one another, like that:
[image: screen shot 2013-09-12 at 14 38 55]

The SCSS is the same and the HTML is much similar like the other problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake in the first problem.

I forgot to set the height of my image and the container.

Now, my SCSS looks like that:

```
.recipe {
    width: $grid-width;
    height: auto;
    margin: $margin-top 0 $margin-bottom $ditter;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

    border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    @include border-radius(0 0 5px 5px);

    .avatar {
        position: absolute;
        top: -15px;
        width: $grid-width;
        margin: 0 auto;
        img {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    .image {
        width: $grid-width - 2px;
        height: 235px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        img {
            width: $grid-width;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }

    .name {
        font-family: Times;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .recipe-controls {
        width: $grid-width;
        .star {
            font-size: 30px;
            margin: 15px;
        }
    }
}
```

But the second problem is still happening.